# In the admin panel of Magento, where can I see entries of the contact us form?

Tags: admin-panel, contact-us

I have made a contact us form for my website. Where can I see the entries of data made by my customers in that form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot see these entries in the Magento backend.

This form will send an e-mail to the address you have set in the backend.

Comment: Glad i could help. if you found my answer helpful could you please accept the answer ? thank you